# Laravel 5.1 - htaccess changes doesn't reflect

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5.1, http-status-code-301

Wanted to do a 301 redirect, but the changes doesn't reflect on site.
Even tried restarting the php webserver.
Tried deleting both the htaccess (root and in /public), and to my surprise the laravel routes still worked fine, don't know how.

Can someone suggest where am I going wrong?

Comment: I would make my own error view and put it in resources/views/errors/301.blade.php and just make a route that returns abort(301); and there you can put the correct link to requested page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out. The issue was PHP webserver. When used local server from directly apache or virtualhost, it worked fine, but using PHP -S web server, the htaccess didn't reflect.

Answer (score -1):

Which platform you are using if windows platform means htaccess file wont work. Use web.config